# npm install Errors on mac 10.7.5

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am learning `mongodb` and as part of my learning process, I installed `mongodb`, `nodejs` and `npm`.  When I execute the instruction npm install, this is the error I get:

```
me$ npm install
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm ERR! Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7 

npm ERR! version not found: mongodb@3.2.1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/Sites/mongodb/chapter1/npm-debug.log
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "gulp test",
        "watch": "gulp watch"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "async": "0.9.0",
        "mongodb": "3.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.8.11",
        "gulp-mocha": "2.0.1",
        "mocha": "2.2.4"
    }
}
```

I created a database called mongodb so it can see it but, I don't know what is wrong. I read the  npm install errors" but nothing points to the similar error so I can solve it myself. Please, help !!

Answer (score 0):

> npm ERR! version not found: mongodb@3.2.1

It means the version `3.2.1` of the mongodb package doesn't exist (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb - currently, last version in 2.1.4).

Just fix the version number in your package.json from:

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "0.9.0",
    "mongodb": "3.2.1"
},
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "0.9.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.4"
},
```

Then re-run `npm install`